# Can't use a column that has the same name as a clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

i am trying to do a join :

```
select * from employee inner join order on employee.employeeid = order.EmployeeId
```

but the word
***order***
 which is the name of the column is recognized as the `order by` i think and it doesn't refer to the column. How can you proceed in SQLite while you have this type of problem?

Comment: Hello, try to use quotes "order" and also "order"."EmployeeId"

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it in square brackets, `[order].EmployeeID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLite: escaping table and column names correctly. Use double quotes around
>   column names, table names, trigger names etc.
>
> ```
> SELECT "column name", "my column", FROM "table name" //Use single quotes around string values
>
> SELECT * FROM "table name" WHERE "column name" = 'string value' //Use two double quotes if e.g. your column name contains a double quote
> ```
>
> (e.g. my”column)
>
> ```
> SELECT "my""column" FROM "my""table"
> ```
>
> https://blog.christosoft.de/2012/10/sqlite-escaping-table-acolumn-names/

So use double quotes:

```
select * from "employee" inner join "order" on employee.employeeid = "order"."EmployeeId"
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this you can use table alias.

```
select * from employee inner join order o on employee.employeeid = o.EmployeeId;
```

Hope this will help you.